# listing files of subfolder issue

Tags: php, mysql

i have several millions files in a folder and there are several subfolders in that folder each subfolder consists of thousands of files . i am able to list all files of given folder using glob function but here in this case as its very high i am getting php fatal error . allowed memory size exhaused try to allocate more memory i know that can be done just by keeping one php.ini file in that subfolder but what i exactly want is listing all .txt extension size in descending order so the bigger file will be at the top and smaller file will be at the bottom but as i have said it is not possible to list millions of file so just like mysql can i list them in page wise or something like top 100 files will be listed in descending order when i click on next page it will show next 100-200 items but i dont want to use database if there is no other way how i can store all these details in database without causing heavy load on server.

```
     <?php
      foreach (glob("files/*") as $filename) {
       echo "uploads/" . "$filename" .  "\n</br>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) insteed of glob();

Try something like this:

```
function printdirs($path) { 
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if(is_dir($path.'/'.$entry))
                printdirs($path.'/'.$entry);
            else
            echo $path . "/" . $entry .  "\n</br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}}

printdirs('uploads');
```

Comment: please  tell how can i achieve my goal

Comment: Please expand on your answer some.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev you are getting what i wanted to do

Comment: @Oden it will printy millions of record without filtering file type and size.i have no problem in listing file using glob but what i want if please read my question